# how to add **** at the end of each row in a dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, text, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to add '****' at the end of the each row of my data frame?

for example

```
detail orientated
marketing and events
community development consultant
leader medical assistant instructor
android developerator project
natural hair care specialist
```

turn to

```
detail orientated ****
marketing and events ****
community development consultant ****
leader medical assistant instructor ****
android developerator project ****
natural hair care specialist ****
```

Comment: yes there sure is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `concat`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('column1', F.concat('column1', F.lit(' ****')))
```

Comment: when I wrote this on CSV all `****` disappeared

Comment: Did you call `write.csv` on `df2`? Not `df`?

Comment: And did you check your file path is correct?